# Takes longer to use SL api createSnapshot of Endurance storage than does taking a manual snapshot via web portal?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I'm using

```
iscsi_mgr = SoftLayer.ISCSIManager(SL.instance(sl_config).client)
iscsi_id = helpers.resolve_id(iscsi_mgr.resolve_ids, iscsi_identifier,'iSCSI')
iscsi = SL.instance(sl_config).client['Network_Storage_Iscsi']
snapshots = iscsi.createSnapshot(id=iscsi_id)
```

I then spin and wait for the number of snapshots taken to become 1 larger than before ( since `createSnapshot` is an async operation )
There I'm using `getManualSnapshots` to return the list of all snapshots.

I've noticed that when using the API I am seeing take anywhere from 15 to 60 minutes to complete this procedure, regardless of the amount of data changed in between snapshots.  Meanwhile the web portal is noticeably faster.  What is the difference between the use of the SL API this way and what is going on via web portal? Is there something I am missing to have the snapshot readily available?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portal uses this method:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Network_Storage/createSnapshot

You could try changing the service that your are using and see if there is any difference:

```
iscsi = SL.instance(sl_config).client['Network_Storage']
snapshots = iscsi.createSnapshot(id=iscsi_id)
```

Regards

Comment: Great, changing to that service is working.  It appears that the `Network_Storage_Iscsi` manager is broken in restore operations.  Are known issues being addressed to this manager?  And if are, what are the differences if `Network_Storage` manager can be used all the while? Saw mention to restore being broken in https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-python/issues/750, Thanks!

Comment: yep, the service is broken and it is already reported in Softlayer. The Network_Storage_Isc‌​si service should work like Network_Storage service, but as you said Network_Storage_Isc‌​si service is broken, they need to fix it. you can use Network_Storage service in order to avoid more issues, I am not sure how many methods from Network_Storage_Isc‌​si service are not working. Also please I will thank you if you can vote and marke the answer as the correct.